# Rails 6 Session Data Not Persisting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, production

I've been battling this for about 24 hours now, and nothing I'm finding in my searches is leading to a solution.

My issue is my session data is not persisting and I can not log in to my app.  Everything worked in Dev mode, but has not yet worked in Production.  I'm using a Rails 6 Api hosted on Heroku and a React front end.  I can successfully make the api call, find the user, and log them in using (I use "puts" to help me log the session at that instance.  The session hash has a session_id and user_id at this point):

```
def login!
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
    puts "login_session: #{session.to_hash}"
end
```

After this the app redirects to the user page or an admin page depending on the users authorization.

When the redirect happens that the user or admin page calls the api to see if the user is authorized using:

```
def logged_in?
    puts "logged_in_session: #{session.to_hash}"
    !!session[:user_id]
end
```

The session is empty. Here is my sessions controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: session_params[:email])
    puts @user.inspect
    if @user && @user.authenticate(session_params[:password])
        
      login!
      render json: {
        logged_in: true,
        user: UserSerializer.new(@user)
      }
    else
      render json: { 
        status: 401,
        errors: ['no such user', 'verify credentials and try again or signup']
      }
    end
end


def is_logged_in?
    if logged_in? && current_user
      render json: {
        logged_in: true,
        user: UserSerializer.new(current_user)
      }
    else
      render json: {
        logged_in: false,
        message: 'no such user or you need to login'
      }
    end
end

def is_authorized_user?
    
    user = User.find(params[:user_id][:id])
    
    if user == current_user
        render json: {
            authorized: true
        }
    else
        render json:{
            authorized: false
        }
    end
end


def destroy
    logout!
    render json: {
      status: 200,
      logged_out: true
    }
end

def omniauth
  @user = User.from_omniauth(auth)
  @user.save
  login!
  render json: UserSerializer.new(@user)
end

private

def session_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password)
end

def auth
    
    request.env['omniauth.auth']
end
```

Would any be able to point me the right direction??

Thank you

Comment: Code looks fine to me. I might be wrong here, but it looks like you're using the controller as an API endpoint (due to JSON responses). Is it possible that the browser never stored the cookie(session) in the first place? Perhaps because the API endpoint is on a different (sub)domain or just because of the way the Javascript handles it.

Comment: Thank you, Yeah I'm using it as an API.  This might be a dumb question but would I have to handle the the cookie differently than in the dev environment ?

Comment: I'm not sure. With our API endpoints we use an API key that the users sends with their API call. So after authenticating, the controller would return an API key in the JSON, which then is stored in a cookie by the JavaScript. Then, in every following API call, they API key is included through a cookie. It's quite a hassle, so unless you're writing a mobile app, you might just want to make the login form synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

I would verify the following:

1. When first authenticated, does the response from the endpoint include the cookie data?
2. Check the cookie store in your browser (there's a few extensions you can use to make this easier) and verify that the domain names match and the content in the cookie is what you'd expect.
3. You can cross reference the cookie ID with the ID in your session store (depending on where you've chosen to store this).
4. Can you verify the cookie contents (user_id) and session contents in the session store.
5. Make sure that the cookie data is being sent on the next request after authenticating (check the request headers in the network tab of your dev tools in the browser).

This is all assuming that you're using a browser to talk to this JSON endpoint. APIs usually don't use cookies as it's a browser thing. Alternative authentication mechanisms might be a short lived token (JWT for example) that is generated when authenticating that can be used for subsequent requests.

Comment: Thank you!  I've been able to verify that the response is NOT including cookie data.  In my Dev environment the cookie is included, but not in Prod.  How would I go about fixing this??

Comment: I would now check through your session/cookie configs per environment. Check the `config/environment.rb` and `config/environment/production.rb` files, as there is a couple of options related to how cookies and sessions are handled. It might help to go through your git history on these files or create a new Rails app in another directory and diff them with yours.

Answer (score 0):

Quick update: I am able to get the "Set-Cookie: _session_id=..." in the response but it is blocked to due to "SameSite=lax" attribute.

I believe I need to change to SameSite = none, but I'm not sure were to do that.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but if you're using Rails 6 API, session has been disabled. You need to add the middleware manually. Here is the documentation [using-session-middlewares](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html#using-session-middlewares)

```rb
# This also configures session_options for use below
config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_interslice_session'

# Required for all session management (regardless of session_store)
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies

config.middleware.use config.session_store, config.session_options
```